# Python webbrowser.open() is not working in VScode (already try two environment )

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I'm trying to use the python `webbrowser.open()` to open a webpage, the code run perfectly, did not has any error in the terminal, but no webpage has pop out.

```
import webbrowser
urlstr='https://www.twse.com.tw'
path=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe "
webbrowser.register('google chrome',None,webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(path))
webbrowser.get('google chrome').open(urlstr,new=1,autoraise=True)
```

[image: terminal]

I tried Python 3.9.2 64-bit and Python 3.8.8 64-bit('base':conda) two environment but have same results.
But when I run the code with .ipynb file, it will pop out the webpage.

**CODE :**
[image: code]

What can I do to make the code run in vscode?

Comment: Have you tried normal way mean just using `webbrowser.open()` is it working?

Comment: @Xitiz ```webbrowser.open()``` is not working either

Answer (score 1):

The same problem with me, I think this is related to VSCode settings.
I've tried to use the terminal inside VSCode by typing "**python <filename.py>**", and it worked well.
It is not the direct solution, but it may help.